# Dynamic Paint Brush not working on canvas

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, dynamic-paint

I'm trying to get the **Dynamic Paint Brush** on my model to touch the **Dynamic Paint Canvas** and I've done this before but it's not working this time and I'm not sure why.

Here is a screenshot of the overall problem and here are screenshots of my settings.

If there is further information needed, let me know and I will provide it

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As you are using the canvas on vertex mode, you need enough vertices in your mesh to draw the colors on. a simple square is not enough. Either subdivide into a grid manually, or add a subsurf modifier set on simple.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add a ***subsurface*** modifier with ***at least 5 divisions*** to get my desired result

There was only 1 face, so the brush was working but I was unable to see it due to the size being so small at .01 on one face without the subsurface modifer

[image]

Comment: At the top of the canvas settings, you have a format of vertex, that is why you need to subdivide to get the vertices that will store the result. Depending on what you are using it for, you can also use image sequence to bake the result to images that you can use for example in a material or displace modifier. Note that images can give better resolution that vertices.